# Stopping a file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form submission:

```
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='startUpload();' >
```

I'm trying to get the file size before upload and if it's too large stop the submission.

`iSize` is reporting the correct file size, the alert is being shown, but the submission continues.

How do I exit the upload once the alert is shown ?

```
function startUpload(){
    var iSize = ($("#myfile")[0].files[0].size / 1024);
    console.log(iSize)
    if (iSize > 10) {
        alert('file size to big');
        return;
    }


      document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      return true;
}

function stopUpload(success){
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span><br/><br/>';
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
      }
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').innerHTML = result + '<label>File: <input name="myfile" type="file" size="30" /><\/label><label><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" /><\/label>';
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'visible';      
      return true;   
}
```

Comment: onsubmit='return startUpload();' and actually return false on its case.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean, please can you explain. Thanks

Comment: Replace "onsubmit='startUpload();'" with "onsubmit='return startUpload();'"

Comment: Replace "return;" with "return false" after the alert. Yet that one is optional I suppose.

Comment: You can to pass in the even object to the onsubmit handler, then call event.preventDefault() when you are sure you dont want to submit the form

Comment: Example of stopping, then manually running the submission: https://jsfiddle.net/v2LzpLth/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass on the return value of the function:

```
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return startUpload();' >
```

*Furthermore on a sidenote, the success part of the function stopUpload() makes less sense if you consider a form.submit() happening in the process. One would have to upload it by sending it to an iframe or by using ajax to make proper use of it.*